# XMonad.Util.Paste.sendKey does not work in some applications?

Tags: xmonad, xmonad-contrib

While experimenting with `XMonad.Util.Paste` from `xmonad-contrib`, I realized that the following key-binding works for some applications (e.g. Firefox and Chromium) but does not work for others (e.g. Emacs, XTerm, Xiate (a GTK-based terminal-emulator)):

```hs
("C-a", sendKey controlMask xK_n)
```

With this key-binding active in XMonad, I can create new windows in Firefox and Chromium (which is bound to `C-n`) by pressing `C-a`. In Emacs, XTerm and Xiate, pressing `C-a` does not translate to `C-n`; in Emacs and Xiate I can only see the cursor "blink" once when I press `C-a`.

Why does this key-binding not translate in any focused application as expected?

Answer (score 0):

As geekosaur in #xmonad:libera.chat pointed out, the respectively targeted application needs to support X11's `send_events` feature.

You can launch XTerm to support that as follows:

```bash
xterm -xrm '*allowSendEvents:true'
```

Emacs seems to support that feature when compiled with Motif toolkit (`--with-x-toolkit=motif`), or with no X toolkit (`--with-x-toolkit=no`).